# Comparing Python integers

Tags: python, types

I have a list of integers below a thousand and a hash function transforming it into a single integer but much larger one. There is a hash function code below:

```
def hash_function(lst):
    hsh = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        hsh += item * pow(10, i * 3)
    return hsh
```

Assume that `lst` has about 4-5 items.
Is comparing two integers more efficient than comparing two lists of much smaller integers? Why or why not? I have to compare a few hundreds thousands of hashes.

Comment: Of course comparing the lists is more efficient. The per item operation is a comparison instead of the hash function.

Comment: As far as I know there are integers in Python based on variable-size, so imho my question is not obvious. Comparing one integer vs comparing a few much smaller integers. Obvious if you have classical implementation of integers such as in C or in Java.

Comment: You can test this with timeit, if you like. IMO, using arbitrary precition ints instead of native ints will make the hash approach even slower by comparison.

Comment: Of course I can, but what I want is you explain me low level comparing  integers mechanism in Python, and its impact on my problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question: `zip(range(len(lst)), lst)` is a reimplementation of `enumerate(lst)`.

Comment: What *kind* of comparisons are we talking about? Equality? Python will only compare enough elements to determine two lists differ, but if your lists are mostly equal then you have to do a lot of comparisons. But your best bet is to *time your actual scenarios*. Use the `timeit` module, devise a few tests, and measure.

Comment: Yup, we are talking about equality. Numbers can be similar and a lot of lists may differ only last item. As I said, I am interested in getting a brief description or explanation of low level comparing equality algorithm integers in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a quick test to show the differences between the builtin list comparisons, and your hash function.

```
import time
import random
import sys
def compareRegular(a, b):
    return a == b

def listHash(lst):
    hsh = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        hsh += item * pow(10, i * 3)
    return hsh

def compareHash(a, b):
    return listHash(a) == listHash(b)

def compareLists(hugeList, comparison):
    output = []
    for i, lstA in enumerate(hugeList[:-1]):
        for j, lstB in enumerate(hugeList[i + 1:]):
            if comparison(lstA, lstB):
                output.append([i, j])
    return output

def genList(minValue, maxValue, numElements):
    output = []
    for _ in range(1000):
        smallList = []
        for _ in range(numElements):
            smallList.append(random.randint(minValue, maxValue))
        output.append(smallList)
    return output

random.seed(123)
hugeListA = genList(-sys.maxint - 1, sys.maxint, 5)
hugeListB = genList(0, 100, 5)

print "Test with huge numbers in our list"
start = time.time()
regularOut = compareLists(hugeListA, compareRegular)
end = time.time()
print "Regular compare takes:", end - start

start = time.time()
hashOut = compareLists(hugeListA, compareHash)
end = time.time()
print "Regular compare takes:", end - start
print "Are both outputs the same?", regularOut == hashOut
print

print "Test with smaller number in our lists"
start = time.time()
regularOut = compareLists(hugeListB, compareRegular)
end = time.time()
print "Regular compare takes:", end - start

start = time.time()
hashOut = compareLists(hugeListB, compareHash)
end = time.time()
print "Regular compare takes:", end - start
print "Are both outputs the same?", regularOut == hashOut
```

On my computer this outputs:

```
Test with huge numbers in our list
Regular compare takes: 0.0940001010895
Regular compare takes: 3.38999986649
Are both outputs the same? True

Test with smaller number in our lists
Regular compare takes: 0.0789999961853
Regular compare takes: 3.01400017738
Are both outputs the same? True
```

The people who develop python definitely spend a bunch of time thinking about stuff like this. I personally have no idea how the built in list comparison actually works, but I'm pretty certain it doesn't execute within the Python interpreter like your hash function will. Many python built in functions and types are backed by native executing C code, the list comparison function likely falls into this category.

Even if you implemented your hash function in a similar way and had it executed natively, it would still likely be slower. You're basically looking at N calls to `pow` or N number comparisons. Even if they are variable size integers, `memcmp` certainly won't take longer than loading the same value from memory **and** performing floating point operations on it.